# Derivation Numerical Method with partial derivatives, vectors, matrices and scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, numerical-methods, partial-derivative, hadamard-product

I need help in finding a way to combine the equations 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} \cdot \delta W = \langle  Y_M^T (\eta^{'}(Y_M W) \odot (\eta(Y_MW)-C)),\delta W \rangle
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\langle\frac{\partial J}{\partial Y_M} , \delta Y_M\rangle_F = \langle  (\eta^{'}(Y_MW)\odot (\eta(Y_MW)-C))W^T, \delta Y_M \rangle_F
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\delta Y_M = \frac{\partial Y_M}{\partial K_m} \cdot \delta K_m = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Y }(Y_{M-1},K_{M-1})...\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Y }(Y_{m+1},K_{m+1})\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial K }(Y_{m},K_{m})\delta K_m
\end{equation}

to find expressions for 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial K_m} \text{, m = 0,...,M-1 and } \frac{\partial J}{\partial W}.
\end{equation}

Here $Y_{m+1} = \phi(Ym,Km)$ indicates an ode numerical method step such as Eulers method that updates a n by 4 matrix $Y_m$. $\langle A,B\rangle_F = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}b_{ij}$ is the inner product between two matrices of the same size. C is an n by 1 vector.$\eta$ is a function that maps from $R^{a*b}$ to $R^{a*b}$. $W$ is a n by 1 vector. $J = J(K_0,K_1,...,K_{M-1},W)$ maps M 4 by 4 matrices and a 4 vector W into a real number. $\odot$ is the Hadamard product. K is a structure containing M 4*4 matrices (from $m = 0$ to $m= M-1$).

All help is appreciated, everything from suggestions where to start to a complete derivation. My idea is to use total differentials, chain rule and/or product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you need too much help, you're mostly done.

If I may introduce a few notations for typing convenience
$$\eqalign{
 \eta &= \eta(Y_MW)
 &{\rm\,\,\,[vector]} \cr
 g &= \eta\odot(\eta-C) \cr
 {\mathcal A_j} &= \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Y}(Y_j,K_j)
 &{\rm\,\,\,[4th\,order\,tensor]}\cr
 {\mathcal B_j} &= \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial K}(Y_j,K_j)
 &{\rm\,\,\,[4th\,order\,tensor]}\cr
 {\mathcal P_{jk}} &= {\mathcal A_{j-1}}:{\mathcal A_{j-2}}:\ldots:{\mathcal A_{k+1}}
 &{\rm\,\,\,[\,j>k+1\,]} \cr
{\mathcal C} &= {\mathcal A}:{\mathcal B} \,\,\,\,\,\,\implies &\,\,{\mathcal C}_{ijmn}=\sum_{kl} {\mathcal A}_{ijkl}{\mathcal B}_{klmn}  \cr
}$$
Note that the double-contraction product notation (:) can be used with matrices and vectors, as well as tensors.  For example 
$$\eqalign{
 X:Y &= \langle X,Y\rangle_F \cr
 x:y &= x\cdot y \cr\cr
}$$
Your first equation can be solved immediately for one of the gradients
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= Y^Tg:dW \cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} &= Y^Tg \cr\cr
}$$
And substituting the third equation 
$$\eqalign{ dY_m &= {\mathcal P_{Mm}}:{\mathcal B_{m}}:dK_m}$$
into the second
$$\eqalign{dJ &= gW^T : dY_M }$$
yields the other gradient
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= gW^T
 :\Big({\mathcal P_{Mm}}:{\mathcal B_{m}}:dK_m\Big) \cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial K_m}
 &= gW^T : {\mathcal P_{Mm}} : {\mathcal B_{m}} \cr\cr
}$$
**NB:** In my notation, components of the gradient tensors are indexed like so 
$$
\Big(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Y}\Big)_{ijkl}
 =
\frac{\partial\phi_{ij}}{\partial Y_{kl}}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question however: what exactly is the rule that allows you to go from $dJ = Y^Tg : dW$ to $\frac{\partial J}{\partial W} = Y^Tg$. Is this the tensor variant of total differentiation?

Comment: Also why can you say that the internal products in $\mathcal{B}_j$ are inner products?

Comment: The double-contraction product is NOT an inner product for 4th order tensors. Although it is an inner product when applied to matrices. Just like the single-contraction product (aka dot product) is an inner product when applied to vectors, but when applied to matrices it's just the normal matrix product.$$ $$As for your other question $$dJ=G:dW \implies G=\frac{\partial J}{\partial W}$$in the case where $(G,W)$ are both vectors or matrices. (For higher-order tensors you should use the *fully* contracted product) Anyway, it's THE defining property of the gradient.